# Calling Python Function from Console

Tags: python, command-line

Would it be possible to call Python codes I wrote in Text Editor from the Python console so that I can interact with it?

Answer (score 7):

If you name your script `*.py` in the text editor you can import it in the console as a module.

Beware - after you imported the script for the first time you can't import it again. If you make changes to the module you can use [`imp.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.reload) or [`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) (for blender versions > 2.71 using python 3.4)

Comment: I wasn't able to do this. Does anybody know if this is still current?

Answer (score 5):

You can retrieve the Text datablock's text as string and run it in the context of the Python Console.

Here's an addon that makes it easy to do so:

[Run Script in PyConsole (Menu)](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?312821-Run-Script-in-PyConsole-%28Menu%29)

Globals of your script will be added to the globals of the Python Console environment.

Comment: That's an useful addon. Is there an option to reset a console in blender?

Comment: As in resetting the scrollback, history and environment (globals and locals)? Well, you can remove members from locals() and globals() and `bpy.ops.console.clear()` resets the scrollback, but the history stays. I tried resetting the console by splitting and joining the area, but joining is buggy.