# Enabling add-on programmatically

Tags: python, add-on

I have been trying to enable Blender addons from Python. I used the following code to implement it:

```
def enable_addon(addon_module_name):
    loaded_defaults, loaded_state = addon_utils.check(addon_module_name)
    if not loaded_state:
        addon_utils.enable(addon_module_name)


enable_addon('object_print3d_utils')
enable_addon('object_boolean_tools')
```

It works for object_print3d_utils, but not for object_boolean_tools, and I'm not sure what could be reason. I get the following error:

RuntimeError: Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/blender.app/Contents/Resources/3.2/scripts/addons/object_boolean_tools.py", line 468, in execute
Operation(context, self.mode)
File "/Applications/blender.app/Contents/Resources/3.2/scripts/addons/object_boolean_tools.py", line 111, in Operation
prefs = context.preferences.addons[**name**].preferences
KeyError: 'bpy_prop_collection[key]: key "object_boolean_tools" not found'

Thank you for any help in advanced!

Comment: Pass `default_set=True`, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/242762/88681.

Comment: The error message is misleading. Unless you pass the `default_set=True` argument, as @scurest said, `addon_utils` treats disabled addons as if they don't exist. This is why you get the key error.  I don't know if it is a bug or a feature but it is annoying.