# Is it possible to build blender scripts in external editor like Atom

Tags: python, scripting

I have little experience scripting thus far but want to develop my skills further. I am particularly interested in autocomplete features and looking to script geometry within one context for Rhino, Blender, and Processing. Atom handles Rhino and processing, but not sure how to make it work with Blender.

Edit: Is it possible to create an atom package for a bpy/bmesh autocomplete library and send scripts directly to blender?

[Here](https://atom.io/packages/rhino-python) is how Atom can be used with Rhino Python:

[image: Atom with Rhino Python]

Scripts can be executed within Atom.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're looking for an atom package for a bpy/bmesh autocomplete library?

Comment: In theory, one can build blender as a python module, but last I heard it wasn't very good or easy to do. I'm not sure if this can plug into atom just by dropping it into the python module directory or if you'll have to build an autocomplete "dictionary" of sorts. (This is me just thinking out loud, for later research.)

Comment: There is a package for sublime: https://github.com/svenfraeys/SublimeBlender

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31126/workflow-for-developing-add-on-script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was doing this with sublime, I added a "build system" to sublime, essentialy "run this shell code on save", that would run a new headless (or not if directed to) blender instance that ran my script. It was slow but it did allow me to leverage an ide for writing my scripts. It's a bit like setting up a testing framework, and I would recommend additionally setting up a testing framework too so you can know if your script is working and still working without manually, visually inspecting your script results, if possible.

Comment: Notably this is just one way you can approach this; Main comments have useful links as well to other setups^