# How To use Visual Studio Code to write blender python script integrated with blender?

Tags: python, scripting

There are different options out there of Ides to write integrated python blender scripts.

I'm a visual studio person and, even though there is no way to use it for that purpose, I was hoping with Visual Studio Code would be different.

I researched and I can use python there, of course, but I was wondering if I can use integrated with blender (intelisense, debugging, blender diagnostics)

please any new finding is welcome. I'm not expecting someone to have the full answers but I am hoping I can compile a soluiton and post here

thanks

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/31126/935)?

Comment: Have you looked at [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVDf2VSmRvk)? It seems to be useful for you, and me!

Answer (score 7):

For Blender 2.8 Jacques Lucke started working on a new VS Code extension that offers the best integration I found so far between VS Code and Blender. [You can find it on GitHub](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/blender_vscode).

You can already create, start and debug Python scripts and addons from VS Code with it. Auto-complete is at the point of this writing missing but planned for the future.

Here is a nice video explaining the setup and how to work with it:

https://youtu.be/q06-hER7Y1Q

Answer (score 2):

I can think of two approaches -

- Remote debugging. Options exist for [pycharm/eclipse](https://code.blender.org/2015/10/debugging-python-code-with-pycharm/) that allow the IDE to remotely debug a script running within blender. I'm not certain if this approach can be adapted to work with VSCode.
- [Build blender as a module](https://en.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule). This option allows you to install the blender binary as a normal python module that can run without a gui in a standard python instance, allowing the script to be debugged like any other script.