# Creating button with flag

Tags: python, scripting

I have such a situation that the names of 3D objects that appear on the scene are display in the panel. If a given 3D object has an appropriate name, its name appears on the panel. Once I have that, I would like to create a button that will appear next to the name of object. Just like on screen.
[image: Current state]

As you can see, it works. My problem is that when I push a button, it works on all objects. I would like this button to work [on/off] and only affect the object it is next to. The button is quite simple, because it only has to select object / point. I know I should use flags, but I don’t know how to do it.

Comment: I know I should  set a property for the operator 
(button) 'row.prop(context.scene.common_properties, `CommonProperties.second_button, text=“Second Button”, toggle=True, icon=‘CHECKBOX_HLT’)` The problem is that when I do, I have two buttons pressed at once.  And I would like the first button to be pressed, the second is not. When the second button is pressed, the first one will be not. I know I should use flags, but I don’t quite know how to do it.

Comment: maybe this will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57551/7777, you'll have to adapt it to 2.8+: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html